# Xmlrpc api requests

Tags: php, apache, apache2, lamp, testlink

I have a testlink installation on one machine with MSSQL server at another machine. So, everything is working fine besides xmlrpc api.

I have already set 2 options

```
$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE; 
$tlCfg->exec_cfg->enabled_test_automation = ENABLED;
```

in config.inc.php file, but can't using http://localhost/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php.

I got HTTP ERROR 500 (Internal server error). I looked through the testlink forum and didn't find more options to configure the connection.

Could you please give me advice what it can be?

#### Update

Testlink version is 1.9.19

PHP version is 7.3.4

Apache version is 2.4.25

## UPDATE

I have found the reason why the api doesn't work. The issue say that php:
`PHP Fatal error call to undefined function mssql_get_last_message() in ../adodb-mssql.inc.php ..` 
[image]